# Can we use common master page for multiple reports in birt?

Tags: birt

I'd like to use common images in my reports and I don't want to change every single report every time I'd like to change an image and some label too.

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can, go to: File - New - New Template.

Change the master page layout and styles, save it.

Next time you create a new report - simply just click - **File - New - New Report** - and on the next page (the page after you select the file name) just select the template you created.

That should do it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is not the solution. The intention was to avoid changing several reports when a logo changes. The correct idea is to put things like masterpage, images and so on into a *.rptlibrary file and *reference* them in the reports (instead of *copying* them which is what happens when they are in a *.rpttemplate file)